# RxSwift - how to prevent flatMapFirst to filter out event emited from subscriber

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have code more less like this:

```
let requestResult = someSubject
    .flatMapFirst{ [weak self] _ -> Observable<ResponseClass> in
        return self?.triggerNetworkRequest() ?? Observable.never()
    }.share()

requestResult.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] response in
    if someCondition {
        self?.someSubject.onNext()
    }
}).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

So I'm basically emitting new onNext event to repeat the network request in some circumstances.

The problem is that emitting the event this way causes that it's still filtred out by flatMapFrist. If I wrap it in

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(10)) {
    self.toggleLikeSubject.onNext()
}
```

it works.

How to prevent this event from being filtered out?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the standard solution looks like this -

```swift
        let requests = PublishSubject<Observable<ResponseClass>>()
        let requestResult: Observable<ResponseClass> = requests.switchLatest()
        requests.onNext(triggerNetworkRequest()) // repeat whenever you need a fresh response
        // subscribe to 'requestResult'
```